# How do I call a function from a keyword?

Tags: jquery

Sorry for now using the most suitable technical words, but at the moment I'm experimenting with jQuery, and I seem to be repeating a certain function quite a lot, is there anyway to reference this function? Maybe by setting it as a variable or similar? Thanks

Comment: *"Maybe by setting it as a variable or similar?"* What happened when you tried?

Comment: I think I got the syntax wrong.. the functions I want to do are '.addClass' and 'removeClass', but I wouldn't know how to put the two into the same variable/function

Comment: If you're having some trouble with syntax, you need to show your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in javascript functions are first class citizens - the following is perfectly legal:

```
var localVariable = someNamespace.someFunction;
localFunction(); // Call function here
```

**Update**

Based on your code snippet, you'd want your function to be declared like so:

```
var showAll = function () {
  var images = $('.gallery li img');
  images.removeClass('hideme');
  images.addClass('showme');
  // nb could be done on one line like so:
  // $('.gallery li img').removeClass('hideme').addClass('showme');
};
```

Which would then be useable like so:

```
showAll();
```

Comment: Okay I think I know what you mean, what am I doing wrong [here](http://i.imgur.com/ZmlXK.png)? And how would I call that function?

Comment: Thank you! This has definitely helped

Comment: I would give you a vote up too but I don't have the privilege!